# Error while making membership request from membership App

Tags: java, corda

We are getting the error while making the membership request from a node which is present in different network to BN node present in different network , but these nodes are present in the same CZ.
Please note :
**1.Node requesting is present in the different network and BN is present in the different network**

- why is the flow flow go to flow hospital?

please find the logs :

```
[INFO ] 2018-11-02T09:55:13,420Z [flow-worker] bno.RequestMembershipFlowResponder.call - Removing the pending request from the database {fiber-id=10000010, flow-id=c3a64756-e2a5-4b5b-9b5d-192b42e1ea05, invocation_id=e815bda6-a90b-4994-9444-44fe225cf24e, invocation_timestamp=2018-11-02T09:55:13.243Z, session_id=e815bda6-a90b-4994-9444-44fe225cf24e, session_timestamp=2018-11-02T09:55:13.243Z, thread-id=94170}
[INFO ] 2018-11-02T09:55:13,423Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] netty.LoggingTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted - Check Server Certpath:^M
  C=JP,ST=Tokyo,L=Tokyo,O=Twentyfive RE,CN=twentyfive.re[BC067977D5EB3F640D1CA6CBF1234552395C0C6C8F48FC60] issued by C=JP,ST=Tokyo,L=Tokyo,O=Twentyfive RE,CN=twentyfive.re[FBCF94F53CC72043635EB6219CA6AA30323C70D1]^M
  C=JP,ST=Tokyo,L=Tokyo,O=Twentyfive RE,CN=twentyfive.re[FBCF94F53CC3434344372043635EB6219CA6AA30323C70D1] issued by C=US,L=New York,OU=Corda,O=R3 HoldCo LLC,CN=Corda Doorman CA[EBEE2E30152940AE19981ED86FE37D7F07A2C213]^M
  C=US,L=New York,OU=Corda,O=R3 HoldCo LLC,CN=Corda Doorman CA[EBEE2E3034343434152940AE19981ED86FE37D7F07A2C213] issued by CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[7CAEA9DFB948012B13890B9AE645851C39170773]^M
  CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[7CAEA9DFB948012B13890B9AE645851C39170773] issued by CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK[null] {}
[INFO ] 2018-11-02T09:55:13,431Z [flow-worker] corda.flow.run - Flow threw exception... sending to flow hospital {fiber-id=10000010, flow-id=c3a64756-e2a5-4b5b-9b5d-192b42e1ea05, invocation_id=e815bda6-a90b-4994-9444-44fe225cf24e, invocation_timestamp=2018-11-02T09:55:13.243Z, session_id=e815bda6-a90b-4994-9444-44fe225cf24e, session_timestamp=2

018-11-02T09:55:13.243Z, thread-id=94170}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must pass in exactly the sessions required to sign the transaction.
        at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:120) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.flows.CollectSignaturesFlow.call(CollectSignaturesFlow.kt:74) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:281) ~[corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:312) ~[corda-core-3.1.jar:?]
        at com.chainthat.businessnetworks.membership.bno.RequestMembershipFlowResponder.call(RequestMembershipFlowResponder.java:80) ~[ct-market-cordapp-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.chainthat.businessnetworks.membership.bno.RequestMembershipFlowResponder.call(RequestMembershipFlowResponder.java:26) ~[ct-market-cordapp-1.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:225) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
        at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:51) [corda-node-3.1.jar:?]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_181]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the list of `FlowSession`s you have passed to `CollectSignaturesFlow` does not exactly match the list of parties from whom signatures are required.

You should debug into your flow and check the difference between the list of parties you've created `FlowSession`s with, and the list of parties who are listed on the transaction's commands.

Comment: I was wondering everything works fine when I am trying the same flow from nodes which are present in our network but it does not work when a node present (client network node) outside  our physical network but this node has registered our node through the cordite  into their network (both the nodes are in same CZ and i can see the nodes in the peers response).I am still trying to get the debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

It works after we restart the network map. I could not able to get the root cause.